# Showing an element during scrolling, hiding it when scrolling stops

Tags: jquery, scroll

I know how to run code when user scrolls to a specific point, but I can't find questions about showing an element while user scrolls (no matter where or to where) then hiding it when user stop scrolling. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fixed positioning on your element, and use this event:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $(element).stop(true, true).show().fadeOut('fast');
});
```

This will show the element while scrolling then fade it out when scrolling has stopped.  The `stop()` method stops the currently-running animation.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p7dde2u2/1)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery dont have event "scrollStop" so you can use a setTimeout to do your action

```
<div>
    <div class="fade">
        Scroll down i will become invisible
    </div>
</div>

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
        $('.fade').show();

    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        // do something
        $('.fade').hide();
    }, 250));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/onqn2gjj/896/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use one function to show the element when scrolling is done immediately, and then hiding it a certain amount of time afterward. If we scroll again, we instead basically "push" the timer a little further back. This is basically the concept of debouncing, which you may have heard of. Therefore, my solution looks like this:

```
var hideTimeout = null;

var show = function() {
  $('#theone').show();
}

var hide = function() {
  $('#theone').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(window).scroll(function(e){
    if (hideTimeout) {
        window.clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
      hideTimeout = null;
    }
    show();

    window.setTimeout(hide, 500);
  });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/386bstgh/1/